# How to recover data from a Form in Symfony4?

Tags: controller, twig, symfony-forms, symfony4

I would like to understand how can I transfer the input data from a form, into another form on another page.

Say I insert a TITLE ("Land of Oz") and a DESCRIPTION ("book for children") on my first page where I have two fields title and description that came from a Form), and then I would like to see them already present in the same fields but on another page... (I also have a title and description fields on my next page but I want the alredy populated with "Land of Oz" and "book for children" values)

I tried to do it with $_POST but it did not work.

In twig (where I input data):

```
    <tr>
        <td align="right"><label for=""><b>Titre *: </b></label></td>
        <td> {{ form_widget(post_form.title) }} </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td align="right"><label for=""><b>Description : </b></label></td>
        <td> {{ form_widget(post_form.description) }} </td>
    </tr>
```

In Controller (of the next page):

```
    $post = new MySite();  

    $post->setTitle('TITLE');             // instead of TITLE I want my data to be displayed
    $post->setDescription('DESCRIPTION'); // instead of DESCRIPTION I want my data to be displayed
```

Answer (score 0):

We would need to see more code from your controller to know exactly how to direct you, but assuming your second form is processed in the controller then you have access the first form's data. So, in your Controller you could use something like:

```
$title = $form['title']->getData();
$description = $form['description']->getData();

$post = new MySite();

$post->setTitle($title);
$post->setDescription($description);
```